# How to place image over p tag?

Tags: html, css, image, padding

I am creating a website for learning. One issue I am having problems with is placing an inserted image over a p tag. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqf6s.png. I used the padding tag to move to p tag text to the left. I want the image of the video player to be in-line with the p tag.

I have tried applying display: `inline-block;` to both the image and the p tag but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Can you show us your code please ?

Comment: You can use div tag and set top, left, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use padding to move the p element to the left, you should use the css `float:left;` and then on the image element `float:right;`. That should probably do the trick..